# Calculadora Windows Forms .Net C#

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una calculadora en Windows Forms ya tengo la clase donde puse los métodos, encapsulamiento y constructor con las operaciones.

Tengo una duda :(
Tengo el código para sumar dos valores que paso por parámetros ya intente varias formas para realizar una suma mas larga o resta mas larga por ejemplo
deseo hacer una suma así (10+10+10+10)=40.
Ya que como lo hice solo me suma los dos primeros porque solo pase 2 parámetros.
desearía saber como hacer el código para cada vez que oprima operador suma (+) me guarde los valores en otro lado y cuando oprima igual (=) si me muestre la sumatoria de todo. Muchas gracias

```
private void Btn_Suma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        operador = "+";
        n1 = double.Parse(TxtValores.Text);
        TxtValores.Clear();
    }

public double Numero1 { get => _numero1; set => _numero1 = value; }
    public double Numero2 { get => _numero2; set => _numero2 = value; }

    public COperaciones(double Num1_Prm,double Num2_Prm)
    {
        Numero1 = Num1_Prm;
        Numero2 = Num2_Prm;
    }


    public double Suma()
    {
        return Numero1 + Numero2;
    }


private void Btn_Resultado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n2 = double.Parse(TxtValores.Text);

        switch (operador)
        {
            case "+":
                operacion = new COperaciones(n1,n2);
                TxtValores.Text = operacion.Suma().ToString();
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias ya realice el paso sugerido

Comment: Cual seria el problema de guardar siempre el resultado como uno de los numeros, y usar el segundo para aplicarlo al primero?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías realizar las siguientes operaciones:

```
double resultado = 0;

private void Btn_Suma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    operador = "+";
    resultado += double.Parse(TxtValores.Text);
    TxtValores.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void Btn_Resultado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (operador)
    {
        case "+":
            resultado += double.Parse(TxtValores.Text);
            TxtValores.Text = resultado;
        break;
    }
}
```

Espero resulte útil.